# Is there a way to add custom primitives?

Tags: modeling, mesh, interface

The first time I had the occasion to need a hexagonal grid mesh, and hexagonal cylindrical grid, I created them, and saved the objects

[[image: custom primitives]]

to a library file. But I'm finding them useful enough that I'd like to be able to add them to the "Add mesh" menu so that I could skip the "append" process. Is there a convenient way to add custom primitives?

Comment: if you are comfortable with python yes there is a way, see the "extra objects" addon

Comment: this question was [already asked](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43675/can-i-configure-blender-to-import-a-costumized-mesh-from-the-shift-a-add-mesh) , answers should go there.

Comment: Its not really the same question. Asset flinger is really good but here I think he was looking for a way to add it to the add menu. It can be done in Python. Create an operator to append the objects  and add it to the ui.

Comment: @Akelian is correct; I would like to be able to insert custom primitives in the Add Mesh menu.